# What is the unit of measure for the distance of BufferWithTolerance in sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, spatial

I found this link
[Create a SqlGeography polygon-circle from a center and radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688922/create-a-sqlgeography-polygon-circle-from-a-center-and-radius)

which says it is meters.   This also shows meters on my system.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems where spatial_reference_id = 4326;
```

However, when I create a circle using this code,  the resulting circle has a radius of about 27 miles when I plot it using google maps api and manually measure the distance,  so something is definitely off.   It should be 1/2 a meter and it's actually 27 miles.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-88.0 44.5)', 4326);
select @g.BufferWithTolerance(.5,.01,1)
```

-Randy

Comment: I think  I figured it out.  It is actually degrees not meters.   Dividing the degrees by 60 will convert it to miles.   That seems to work for me anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit will be the same as the unit of the coordinate system i.e degrees if you use geographical coordinates, meters if you use UTM or feet if you use some of the american projections.

Comment: Thanks Morten.   I'd like to mark your answer as correct, but how do I know what the unit of the coordinate system is?

    SELECT unit_of_measure FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems where spatial_reference_id = 4326

that query return metre, but for me it seems to be using degrees not meters.

Comment: YOu need to check up the details of the projection. For a given projection, the unit is always defined.

Comment: Look it up on http://spatialreference.org/ - and then have a look at the wkt-representation. Well, I have to admit that it is not easy to find....

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit further: the unit of epgs 4326 cannot be meters - just think about one degree along equator or along a meridian is approx 110 kms, whereas one degree east-west at one of the poles is 0 meters...

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at the `well_known_text` col in `sys.spatial_reference_systems` you'll see the unit for 4326 is degrees. This is the unit used for describing the location of points etc. and distance in a planar system. The `unit_of_measure` column is the units used for distance between points and areas when using ellipsoidal types.

So, you're using `Geometry` (the SQL planar type) which uses the WKT unit. If you were to be using `Geography` (the SQL ellipsoidal type) then the `unit_of_measure` is used for distances etc.

You can see this in these examples:

**Geometry**

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
DECLARE @g2 geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-88.0 44.5)', 4326);
SET @g2 = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-88.0 44.0)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@g2)

0.5
```

(Distance in degrees)

**Geography**

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @g2 geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-88.0 44.5)', 4326);
SET @g2 = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-88.0 44.0)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@g2)

55558.5621458782
```

(Distance in metres)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx#differences